# Firefox 6 javascript in addressbar

Tags: javascript, firefox

Whatever I type after "javascript:" in the address in firefox 6, firebug says "uncaught exception: ReferenceError: document is not defined". If I try window, it says "uncaught exception: ReferenceError: window is not defined."

If I type the same code in the firebug command line, it works. What gives?

Comment: My coworker had the same issue. Apparently it was a security hole or something. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Append a fun little JS app to a website.

Comment: If it's just you, why not just use firebug? FWIW, I think it still works in Google Chrome.

Comment: use a bookmarklet instead of js in the address bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior was filed as a in the Mozilla project and resolved per [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433).

Comment: Thanks. I had abandoned this question after doing some more searching and finding that FF 6 has a sandbox developer tool.

Comment: @user828584: Indeed, using the Web Console (Ctrl-Shift-K) is the preferred way to run JavaScript now.